# What is the source of the Earth and Moon wallpaper?

Tags: macos, wallpaper

What is the original source of this wallpaper, introduced in Mountain Lion? I'm guessing was taken on a Gemini or Apollo spaceflight, but I can't find it in any of NASA's albums, and the image has been re-uploaded so many times that Google Image Search isn't bearing any fruit either.

[image: Earth and Moon wallpaper]

Photo from [here](http://news.softpedia.com/newsImage/Download-the-Awesome-OS-X-Mountain-Lion-Wallpapers-2.jpg/).

Comment: The scale of the moon and the position of the earth's shadow give me the feeling that this might be photoshopped together, but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

It is clearly a Photoshop creation, as the shadows do not concur to the actual position of the celestial objects.